# Is a Mac Required for Packaging Apache Cordova App?

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I was reading how to package and deploy Apache Cordova apps to the Apple Store; but it almost seems as though one needs a Mac in order to do so.

Is this correct?

I've seen a few questions on SO about this but was wondering if this is still the case...

This is the documentation I was reading: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/#package-the-ios-version-of-your-app

> Step 1: Request a distribution certificate A distribution certificate
>   identifies your team or organization.
>
> If your team already has one and you want to reuse it, see How to
>   share an iOS distribution certificate. Then, skip straight to the
>   Modify the settings of your app section.
>
> If you don't have a distribution certificate yet, continue on with
>   this section and we'll help you set one up.
>
> Start Xcode.
>
> If you haven't installed Xcode, see the First, **install a few things
>   onto your Mac** section of the iOS setup guide.

Comment: Yes, a Mac is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need Mac for build & sign and upload it to store. You will need your app screenshots and videos for a lot of different apple device also. iOS emulators only running in Mac. You can rent Mac on internet. I suggest, bought your own machine. If you have limited budget, you can buy second hand mac mini. You can try your chance with WM also but full hd simulator for ipad very bad.

Comment: OK thanks.  It's surprising in this day and age that an actual Mac (even a VM) would be needed but at least this confirms it.